# how to refresh/reset the model so that it becomes new again

Tags: laravel

My Service:

```
protected $review;
public function __construct(Review $review){
   $this->review = review;
}

public function addReview(){
   $this->review->text = "nice";
   $this->review->save();
}
```

My controller:

```
protected $reviewService;
public function __construct(ReviewService $review){
  $this->reviewService = $review;
}


public function review(){
 $this->reviewService->addReview();
 $this->reviewService->addReview();

}
```

What happens is I call addReview two times. but I want $this->review to become totally new when calling it the second time. If we execute above code, only one entry gets inserted . I want it to insert two times.

Way 1)

```
public function addReview(){
   $this->review->text = "nice";
   $this->review->save();
   $this->review = new Review(); //I don't want to do that
}
```

but i don't want to use 'new' in a function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the point of Review being passed through the constructor?

Comment: Can you just add a function to your `ReviewService`, say `refreshReview()`, that calls `$this->review = new Review()` and call that before the second `addReview()`? Also, why don't you want to use `new Review()`? I don't quite get what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overly concerned with the new operator.  It seems like you should be using the new operator here, since you are wanting to create a new review.  However, you should not be using the class property.

```
public function addReview() {
   $review = new Review();
   $review->text = "nice";
   $review->save();
   // ... whatever you need to do with this new $review, return it? add it to a collection?
}
```

I suppose the reason for avoiding `new` would be so you can mock the Review class, and this is where the waters get a little muddy with Eloquent model concerns.  There really should be no need to mock entities.  Using `new Review` isn't a problem here, the problem is `$review->save()` hitting the database.  An alternative is to move the concern of *persisting the entity* to a repository class and mocking the repository.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here?

new Review() would create a new instance of the review model, but not yet persist it to the database.

Do you want to create a completely new model to be saved in the database? If yes, use Review::create().

->refresh() would get retrieve the information from the database again for the model it is called on. that information could have been changed from some other place in your application.

Answer (score 0):

So something like this might work:

```
public function addReview(){
    $this->review = Review::create();
    $this->review->text = "nice";
    $this->review->save();
}
```

Comment: still not working.. only one record gets stored in db.

Comment: OK, I think I know what you are asking for now. See update.